# Local characteristics of a random field

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-graphs

Let $T \neq 0$ be a finite collection of 'sites'. A random field $X$ on $T$ with values in $L$ is a random vector $(X_i)_{i \in T}$ having $L$-vlaue components. If $L$ is finite, the distribution of $X$ is specified by the probability mass function
\begin{align}
\pi_X(x) = \mathbb{P}(X_i = x_i : i \in T), \qquad x \in L^T,
\end{align}
and by a joint density function $\pi_X$ in the continuous case $L \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

The local characteristics of a random field $X$ are 
\begin{align}
\pi_i(x_i | x_{T \setminus i})=\pi_X(X_i =x_i | X_{T \setminus i} = x_{T \setminus i})
\end{align}
whenever well-defined.

Now, I want to show that the local characteristics 
\begin{align}
\pi_1(x|y) = \pi_2(y|x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\big[-\frac{1}{2}(x-y)^2\big]
\end{align}
are well-defined but do not define a proper joint distribution. Do I have to show that
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\big[-\frac{1}{2}(x-y)^2\big]\ dx\ dy \neq 1 ?
\end{align}
How to show the well-definedness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the conditional probability density function should not be inegrate to 1. Let local characteristics define a proper joint distribution $\pi_{1,2}(x,y)$. Then

$$\pi_1(x\mid y) = \frac{\pi_{1,2}(x,y)}{\pi_2(y)}, \quad \pi_2(y\mid x) = \frac{\pi_{1,2}(x,y)}{\pi_1(x)}.
$$
L.h.s.'s of this equalities are the same. Then r.h.s.'s are equal:
$$\frac{\pi_{1,2}(x,y)}{\pi_2(y)}= \frac{\pi_{1,2}(x,y)}{\pi_1(x)} \iff \pi_1(x)=\pi_2(y) \text{ for any } x,y.
$$
This cannot be true.

To show the well-definedness of $\pi_1(x\mid y)$, check whether it is a p.d.f. You could know what distribution has such p.d.f.